# Java - Get all values around a number

Tags: java

I want to make a Matrix which changes the values/make a sum of the values of the number on the place plus over, under, left and right of it.

- When there is no element then it should be added 0.

Currently the problem is that `9  3  9 | 6  12  6 | 9  3  9` but they should be `9 10 9 | 6 10 6| 9 10 9` (just from left to right and left to right) and I don't know who I get the values above.

Can anybody help me with that?

Furthermore I wanted to do that in a loop that is automatic but then I get always get this `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

- The Input Matrix is `1 8 1 | 4 2 4 | 1 8 1` and the outcome should be `13 12 13 | 8 26 8 | 13 12 13`

  ```
  public class Matrix {
      public static void main(String[] args) {

      int[][] matrix = { { 1, 8, 1 }, { 4, 2, 4 }, { 1, 8, 1 } };
      print(matrix);

      System.out.println("\n");
      int[][] blur = blurMatrix(matrix);
      print(blur);
  }

  public static int[][] blurMatrix(int[][] matrix) {
      if (matrix == null)
          return null;
      if (matrix.length <= 0)
          return null;

      int[][] blur = new int[matrix.length][];

      for (int row = 0; row < blur.length; row++) {
          blur[row] = new int[matrix[row].length];

          for (int col = 0; col < blur[row].length - 1; col++) {
              int cellValue = matrix[row][col];
              int nextColValue = matrix[row][col + 1];
              // int lastColValue = matrix[row][col-1];
              // int nextRowValue = matrix[row+1][col];
              // int lastRowValue = matrix[row-1][col];

              blur[row][col] = cellValue + nextColValue;// +lastColValue+nextRowValue+lastRowValue;
          }

          int lastColumnIndex = blur[row].length - 1;
          blur[row][2] = blur[row][0];
          blur[row][1] = matrix[row][2] + matrix[row][0] + matrix[row][2];

      }

      return blur;

  }

  public static void print(int[][] m) {

      if (m == null) {
          System.out.print(" no matrix to print!");
          return;
      }

      for (int row = 0; row < m.length; row++) {

          for (int col = 0; col < m[row].length; col++) {

              System.out.print(m[row][col] + "  ");

          }
          System.out.println("");
      }

  }
  }
  ```

Comment: Didn't downvote but problem statement isn't clear, provide input matrix and expected output matrix

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: Whats the problem with the addition that I did now and how can I do this with the values above and down of the number

Comment: following your description, first number of the resulting matrix should be 0(top) + 0(left) + 1(itself) + 8(right) + 4(bottom) = 13. It wouldn't be the 9 you are expecting.

Comment: You get ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException whe you try to access index -1 or one that is after the last one. For example you have 3 elements in your array (indices 0, 1 an 2) then you get OutOfBounds when you use index -1 or 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a condition, an tertiary if-then-else expression.

```
int cols = matrix[row].length;

            int nextColValue = col+1 < cols ? matrix[row][col+1] : 0;
            int lastColValue = col-1 >= 0 ? matrix[row][col-1] : 0;

            ... + nextColValue + lastColValue + ...
```

Of course you could do:

```
int valueAt(int[][] m, int row, int col) {
     if (0 > row || row >= m.length) {
         return 0;
     }
     int[] v = m[row];
     if (0 > col || col >= v.length) {
         return 0;
     }
     return v[col];
}

... = valueAt(matrix, row, col)
    + valueAt(matrix, row-1, col)
    + valueAt(matrix, row+1, col)
    + valueAt(matrix, row, col-1)
    + valueAt(matrix, row, col+1);
```

The problem of matrix[0][-1] causing an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException is therewith avoided.

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement your

> When there is no element then it should be added 0

so check on each row or col ±1 if you left the bounds of your array

Answer (score 0):

```
  public static int[][] blurMatrix(int[][] matrix){
    if(matrix == null || matrix.length <= 0)
      return null;

    int[][] returnMatrix = new int[matrix.length][matrix[0].length];
    for (int row = 0; row < matrix.length; row++) {
      for (int col = 0; col < matrix[row].length; col++) {
        int topValue = row == 0 ? 0 : matrix[row-1][col];
        int bottomValue = row == matrix.length-1 ? 0 : matrix[row+1][col];
        int leftValue = col == 0 ? 0 : matrix[row][col-1];
        int rightValue = col == matrix[row].length-1 ? 0 : matrix[row][col+1];
        int cellValue = matrix[row][col];

        int sum = topValue + leftValue + cellValue + rightValue + bottomValue;
        returnMatrix[row][col] = sum;
      }
    }

    return returnMatrix;
  }
```

input

1  8  1
4  2  4
1  8  1

output

13  12  13
8  26  8
13  12  13